# OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I have a list of id users, and I need to get listitems which are created by those users's list.

I use this code to get it :

```
>  for (var i = 0; i < listId.lenght; i++) {
                var queryGetACT = "?$filter=(Author/Id) eq '" + listId[i] + "'";

                getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, 'Activites', queryGetACT, '', '');

            }
```

is there a way to get all Items in one query ; like using

```
var queryGetACT = "?$filter=(Author/Id) in  '" + listId + "'";
```

and not need to use the for .
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use the 'or' in your variable? Like:

```
var queryGetACT = "?$filter=(Author/Id) in  '" + listId[1] + "' or (Author/Id) in '" + ListId[2} + "' (Author/Id) in '" + ListId[3] + "'";
```

You can then use a for loop to create the Url string only and put the "getListItems" command outside the for loop. Or don't you want to use any for loop at all?